# WinForms DatagridViewComboboxColumn "enter key"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a datagridview with an editable combobox column, but everytime I press "Enter" on the current combobox, the text I'm writing disappears.

```
private void dgView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgView1.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
    {
        if (dgView1.CurrentCell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxCell))
        {
            if (!((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue))
            {

                ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex]).Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void dgView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
    {
        ComboBox cbo = (ComboBox)e.Control;
        cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;                 
    }
}
```

I also tried adding the event handlers: "on key press", "on key down" and "on key up" but same problem happens.

How can I keep the current text when I press "Enter" key?

Comment: can you share your xaml code

Comment: there is no xaml code, Im using windows forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` does not accept any value which is not contained in the `Items` collection. So when user types in a new value, the current cell does simply not store the value after editing. You have to find another way to get the last value right after cell being edited. We can get the actual `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` in the `EditingControlShowing` event handler, that control is actually a `ComboBox`, we can handle the `TextChanged` event. The best `DataGridView` event to handle to submit the new value (add to `Items` and show in the current cell) is the `CellEndEdit` event. So here is the code you should do, I've tested it and looks like it works as what you expected:

```
//use some variable to store the last edited value
string editingValue;
//EditingControlShowing event handler
private void dataGridView1_EidtingControlShowing(object sender, 
                                  DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
  var combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
  if(combo != null){
     combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
     combo.TextChanged += (s,ev) => {
       editingValue = combo.Text;
     };
  }
}
//CellEndEdit event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  var comboColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
  if(comboColumn != null && editingValue != "" && 
     !comboColumn.Items.Contains(editingValue)){
     comboColumn.Items.Add(editingValue);
     dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = editingValue;
  }
}
```

Note that the cell value is supposed to be `string` which is why the `editingValue` is declared as `string`, otherwise, you may have to convert the `Text` of the editing comboBox to the correct type of `editingValue`.